# Script injection via json_encode() using PHP

Tags: php, json, security

Is it possible to inject properties into a JSON-String using PHP json_encode()?

Or would be the following example vulnerable:

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['q'];
$api_call = array('search' => $search);
do_my_api_call(json_encode($api_call));
?>
```

This should output something like

```
{"search":"my input string"}
```

This would be an outcome to avoid:

```
{"search:"my input string","function":"do something weird to my REST-API"}
```

If the second one is possible with a manipulated query, how should I quote the input string?

Comment: add a checksum, or a crypto signature and if your string is tampered with it will fail.

Comment: The whole point of `json_encode` is that it makes your output safe to use in JavaScript.

Comment: when using `json_decode` you can simply count the keys (it must be 1) and that the key is 'search' and nothing else.

Comment: A checksum seems to me a very good idea. As long as I develop the API, this should be possible. For third party solutions it is different. Perhaps I did not asked the question the right way. The decoder on the other side seems to be as important as the encoder. Even if PHPs json_encode() is secure, the other side might not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to inject values this way. Only if you'd be cobbling together JSON by hand would this be possible, e.g.:

```
$json = sprintf('{"search":"%s"}', $search);
```

However, if you're using `json_encode`, it is aware of your data types and array structures and will properly escape characters so as to produce an accurate JSON representation of the given input. It cannot be tricked by quotes or other special characters in the input.

Comment: The only footnote here is that certain character sets may create artifacts that bypass the proper escaping, depending on your JSON encoding implementation. I believe both the php5-json and php5-common libraries are impervious to this, but I could be wrong.